# Difference between null!=variable and variable!=null

Tags: java, null, comparison, compare

What is the difference between `null!=variable` and `variable!=null`
Which method is perfect to use?

```
if ((null != value1) || (null != value2) || (null != value3)) {
            .......
            .......
            .......
}
```

or

```
if ((value1 != null) || (value2 != null) || (value3 != null)) {
                .......
                .......
                .......
}
```

Please suggest the best one and the logical change between these?

Comment: No difference. In the olden days, well perhaps still today ;-), `constant != x` was often recommended in languages like C. This was called [Yoda Conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) and helped to avoid cases like `x = constant` as `constant = x` would raise a compiler error. (However, in Java the only case when this matters is when doing a comparison with a `boolean` which should be avoided anyway.)

Comment: I have seen codes comparing null with variable, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Well, you have to make sure the expression is *not* null before a method is attempted to be invoked upon it - lest a NPE is raised. However it doesn't matter if it is `null != x` or `x != null`. Pick one and *be consistent* (which also means following the form already used in a project).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No difference.

But people quite often write "abc".equals(foo), instead of foo.equals("abc"), to avoid null point exception.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is different.

I prefer `value != null` for purely readability reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Both the ways of comparision are correct.There is logically no difference but programmers prefer to use value!=null.

Answer (score 2):

`null != value` is a hold-over from C. In C, your code will be compiled with no warning in this way:
`if (variable = null)` (it's a wrong code), while you actually probably meant `if (variable  == null)`.

But in Jave both these two styles are OK.

Answer (score 2):

In C assignment looks similar to comparison:

```
lvalue = rvalue;
lvalue == rvalue;
```

lvalues (variables) can be assigned to. rvalues can be expressions. Null cannot be assigned to, so if you adhere to use null as the lvalue in comparison, then the compiler will catch the ommision of the second equal sign in a statement like

null = rvalue;

Where you might accidentally assign null with:

lvalue = null;

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there is not a difference but I haven't ran across something that is

```
null != value2
```

I always see it as value2 !=null and like thihara said its easier for readability.
I think its also good to keep it the way value != null for beginner programmers who could possibly go over some ones code might get a little lost on the concept even though there is no difference.